# Install git in Windows 10

Tags: git, path, environment-variables, development-environment

I have installed git in my pc (Windows 10) and set the environment variable path also.

But upon downloading WPCS using git `git clone -b master https://github.com/WordPress-Coding-Standards/WordPress-Coding-Standards.git wpcs`, I get the following error

`'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The Git directory path is `C:\Program Files\Git` and I have set the environment variable as  `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd.`

Can anyone suggest me what might be the problem here?

I have tried these commands also

[image]

Comment: What is "the environment variable"? What does `echo %PATH%` show? Which Git version did you install? Why haven't you just installed Git for Windows, which sets everything up for you?

Comment: @ CodeCaster where I have to try this? I install from here https://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's surely a problem of environment variable refresh (accepting that you selected the good option to update the PATH in the installer).

Environment variables (and, so the PATH) of a process (here `cmd.exe`) are inherited from the ones of the parent process at the creation of the process.

When the env var is rightly set, restarting the computer is a solution that always works.

You could also, as a workaround, open the task manager and kill and restart all the `explorer.exe` process to force the refresh of env variables.

And then all the new processes created from him will have the good refreshed values.
That should work (depending on how you open you command prompt ;) )

Comment: Thanks but before you post I got the answer. but I accepted your answer for the clear explanation it might be helpful to others :).

Comment: Yeah, I saw it before posting but that was the goal of my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Please select the option `Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt` when installing `git`:

[image]

The option basically adds the path `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` to the `Path` System Variable of Windows, make sure you have it there:

[image]

Also try to close the cmd window and open it gain, or even try to restart your PC.

Comment: Yes, i have selected this also.

Comment: yeah I have set system variable also.

Comment: Can you try to close the cmd window and open it again?

Comment: @KataI got it. I just restart my pc now its working fine thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Katal Thanks. But this is not the solution for me but this also one of the cases we need to check So, For your effort upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed the git-scm.com version, you can use my second favourite on top of it, Git for Windows (https://gitforwindows.org)

It will support your Git installation out of the box without messing around with environment variables and it uses Git Bash, which emulates a common Linux command line, so most git commands you will find around on the web will work for you

If you do this, you shouldn't try to run git directly from the Windows command line, but from the Git Bash command line, which will be accessible everywhere in Windows from the right click menu